# how to make ubuntu to remember the login keying password

Tags: password, keyrings

I want my system to remember the keyring password of my chat account login as well as broadcast account. Many times i clicked on remember this keyring password but it not working fine; i mean whenever i boot up computer it prompts for keyring password. isn't any way to system to remember the keyring password; or to tell system not to ask keyring password until application is loaded i mean started.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link. It worked for me. Solution is under comment #3. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/745780

I believe that if your login and keyring passwords are the same, you should not receive a keyring password prompt.

Comment: Hey brian i can't understand which two password you are talking: my keyring password is same for all keyring and my chat account password of facebook is different.

Comment: Hey brian there is no default.keyring file in .gnome2/keyrings/